Why won't my UserForm text field not update programmatically?
I'm writing VBA in Microstation and I want to populate a text field PathToScan with the active design file's path, which is ActiveDesignFile.Path.
What I'm currently attempting has worked just moments ago but for some reason isn't working now.
This is the code I'm using to populate the text field.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Debug.Assert TypeOf Me.PathToScan Is TextBox
    Debug.Assert TypeName(ActiveDesignFile.Path) = "String"
    Debug.Assert ActiveDesignFile.Path <> ""
    
    Me.PathToScan.Text = ActiveDesignFile.Path
    Debug.Assert Me.PathToScan.Text = ""
    
    Do Until Me.PathToScan.Text = ActiveDesignFile.Path
        Debug.Print Me.PathToScan.Text, ActiveDesignFile.Path
        Me.PathToScan.Text = ActiveDesignFile.Path
        Debug.Assert Me.PathToScan.Text = ActiveDesignFile.Path 'this is where it catches
    Loop
End Sub

I can also make the change myself to the value of the TextBox, and Debug.Print Me.PathToScan.Text correctly returns the value that I entered manually.
And now I'm seeing that the definition Me.PathToScan.Text = ActiveDesignFile.Path always defines Me.PathToScan.Text as the empty string.
What could be causing this?

The issue is that the handler for a change to PathToScan was resetting the value to "" due to a failure in another calling function:
Private Sub PathToScan_Change()
    Me.PathToScan = TrimDoubleQuotes(Me.PathToScan) 'this was returning blank by accident
End Sub

This change clears it up.
